# How to convert the name into id and save it to database as id in PHP?

Tags: php, database, authentication

I am making simple mail system in PHP.

I used two table:

> 1. users table
> 2. messages table

I used login from users table and have used session too.
while sending message using id message are sending. But, when I use their names in "mto" field it automatically takes 0 id..

Can anybody answer me?

**compose button code:**

```
<a  class="btn btn-block btn-compose btn-lg" id="loginButton"><i class="fa fa-" ></i> Compose Mail </a>
        <!-- The login modal. Don't display it initially -->
        <form id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" style="display: none;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">To</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="from" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="to" value="<?php echo 'name' ?>"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Subject</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ssubject" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Message</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <textarea name="smessage" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

[image: messages table]

[image]
[image]

User id is linked with to and from field of messages table.
[image: compose]

If we put the id then it takes id but I want to take name from user name and stores the id in table of messages.

Please help me.

```
<?php
include('../session.php');
$from="$session_id";
$to=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["to"]);
$subject=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ssubject"]);
$message=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["smessage"]);
if($from==$to){
    echo "Message could not be sent";
    die();
}
if($from>1 && $to>1){
    echo "Message could not be sent";
    die();
}



//echo $to.$message;
//validate before insert
if(strlen($subject)>50){
    echo "Subject was too long";
    die();
}
if(strlen($message)>150){
    echo "Message was too long";
    die();
}
include('../dbsource.php');
$mysqli=connect();

if(insert($mysqli,$from,$to,$subject,$message)>0)

{
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
        "alert('Message was successfully sent');".
        "</script>";
   // $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';


    }
else
{
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
        "alert('there was error sending message.. please try it later');".
        "</script>";

}
?>


<?php
function insert($mysqli,$from,$to,$subject,$message){   
    $mdate=date('Y-m-d');
    $mtime=date('H:i:s');   
    $query = "INSERT INTO messages (mfrom,mto,subject,message,mdate,mtime)".
        "VALUES ('$from','$to','$subject','$message','$mdate','$mtime')";
    if($mysqli->query($query)>0)
        return($mysqli->insert_id);
    else
        return 0;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**but when i use theie name in "mto" field it automatically takes 0 id**
- This is because of mto field has type int you cannot store character in int type, change it to varchar if you want to store name. however rather then store the name you can make a relation with user table, its a better way.

Comment: i have realtion with users and message table, user "id" has relation with messages "to" and "from" field